# Click outside custom context menu to close it

Tags: angular

How can I close a CUSTOM context menu when clicking outside the menu?

Suppose the custom *simplified* context menu is open. Any click on a button, thus outside of the context menu, should close the context menu and trigger the button action.

You can find this custom context menu in many stackoverflow posts. It works nice. You can find a working example [via this nice short StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emcjbp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontextmenu%2Fcontextmenu.component.html). Just start the example, right click to open the custom context menu. Now try to close that context menu by clicking outside the menu.

In short, the simplified **CUSTOM** context menu is:

```
<div class="contextmenu" [ngStyle]="{'left.px': x, 'top.px': y}">
  this is your contextmenu content
</div>
```

With the code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contextmenu',
  templateUrl: './contextmenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contextmenu.component.css']
})
export class ContextmenuComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {}
  @Input() x=0;
  @Input() y=0;
}
```

The parent:

```
<div (click)="disableContextMenu()" oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <ul>
        <li (contextmenu)="onrightClick($event)">right click me!</li>
    </ul>
    <div *ngIf="contextmenu==true">
        <app-contextmenu [x]="contextmenuX" [y]="contextmenuY"></app-contextmenu>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the logic:

```
  contextmenu = false;
  contextmenuX = 0;
  contextmenuY = 0;

  onrightClick(event) {
    this.contextmenuX = event.clientX
    this.contextmenuY = event.clientY
    this.contextmenu = true;
  }
  disableContextMenu() {
    this.contextmenu = false;
  }
```

Comment: Use this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-click-outside

Comment: Thank you. When a click outside the context menu is done on an other button, will that click BOTH trigger the (clickOutside)=handler($event) AND the button?

Comment: Yes it will trigger outside click for the context menu and button click for button without any problem

Comment: common approach of attaching document listener does not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thank you for making great suggestions!** Based on parts of different solutions, I finally was able to synthesize an elegant solution. Further improvements are very welcome!

When clicking outside the context menu, the context menu is closed. When opening the context menu and clicking on a button (or so), still works AND the opened context menu is closed.

Custom context menu: layout: no change:

```
<div class="contextmenu" [ngStyle]="{'left.px': x, 'top.px': y}">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let menuItem of theMenuItems">
            <span (click)="outputSelectedMenuItem( menuItem)">{{ menuItem }}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Custom context menu: logic -- changes marked:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-contextmenu',
    templateUrl: './contextmenu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contextmenu.component.css']
})
export class ContextmenuComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() x = 0;
    @Input() y = 0;
    @Input() menuitems = '';
    theMenuItems = [];
    @Output() menuItemSelected = new EventEmitter();
    // ADDED: 
    @Output() clickedOutside = new EventEmitter();

    // CHANGED: 
    constructor(private eRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.theMenuItems = this.menuitems.split(';');
    }

    // ADDED: 
    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    clickout(event) {
        if (!this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
            this.menuItemSelected.emit();
        }
    }

    outputSelectedMenuItem(menuitem: string) {
        this.menuItemSelected.emit(menuitem);
    }
}
```

Parent: only the context menu layout: added: clickedOutside

```
<div *ngIf="contextmenu===true">
  <app-contextmenu [x]="contextmenuX" [y]="contextmenuY" [menuitems]="showMenuOptions()"
                   (clickedOutside)="clickedOutsideMenu()"
                   (menuItemSelected)="handleMenuSelection2($event)"></app-contextmenu>
</div>
```

Parent: logic:

```
// Added: 
clickedOutsideMenu() {
    this.disableContextMenu();
}

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
}

showMenuOptions() {
    return 'Menu option 1;Menu option 2';
}

onrightClick(event, parameter1: number, parameter2: string) {
    this.contextmenuX = event.clientX - 100;
    this.contextmenuY = event.clientY;
    this.contextmenu = true;
    //... save the parameters ... here parameter1 and parameter2
    const menuHeight = this.showMenuOptions().split(';').length;
    const maxY = this.innerHeight - (menuHeight * 30);
    if (this.contextmenuY > maxY) {
        this.contextmenuY = maxY;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}

disableContextMenu() {
    this.contextmenu = false;
}

handleMenuSelection2(menuselection: string) {
    this.errorMessage = '';
    if (menuselection === 'Menu option 1') {
        this.requestRapportageSetToFailure();
    } else if (menuselection === 'Menu option 2') {
        this.requestRapportageRestart();
    }
    this.contextmenu = false;
}
```